# XML file not getting written using Unity and C#

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine

I am trying to **save a list** into XML and later **load** the XML back into that list.
Most of it appears to work well with the exception being the actual `Save` method.

Here is my code. The problem is that **SaveInformation.xml** is not getting created.

```
[XmlRoot("SaveInformation")]
public class SaveInformation {

    [XmlArray("stat")]
    [XmlArrayItem("PlayerData")]
    public PlayerData[] stat;

    public void Save(string path){
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveInformation));
        using(var stream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create)){
            serializer.Serialize (stream, this);
            vstream.Close();
        }
    }

    public static SaveInformation Load(string path){
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SaveInformation));
        using(var stream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Open)){
            return serializer.Deserialize (stream) as SaveInformation;
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the `Load` and `Save` methods:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class StoreData : MonoBehaviour {

    public static void Load(){
        var saveInformation = SaveInformation.Load(
            Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "SaveInformation.xml"));

        Debug.Log("Loaded");
    }

    public static void Save(){
        SaveInformation obj = new SaveInformation();

        obj.Save(Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath,
            "SaveInformation.xml"));

        Debug.Log("Saved");
    }
}
```

Here is the Class that should be passing XML **stat** and **PlayerData**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[XmlRoot("PlayerDatabaseCollection")]
public class PlayerDatabase : MonoBehaviour {
    [XmlArray("stat")]
    [XmlArrayItem("PlayerData")]
    public List<PlayerData> stat = new List<PlayerData>();
}
```

And here is the Data itself

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData {
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name;
    [XmlAttribute("current")]
    public int Current;
    [XmlAttribute("max")]
    public int Max;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stream.Flush()?

Comment: Also, your Save method used vstream. Was that previously declared or something? Your main stream is called stream, not vstream. You might be using the wrong stream here.

Comment: It could throw an "DirectoryNotFoundException" if the folder `Application.persistentDataPath` does not exist when the `Save` method is executed. In which case, create the folder first.

Comment: Thank you Alexandru, Strea.Flush() made no difference.
I do not see the use of vstream though, where is that?

Comment: @kennyzx i found the location of the .xml (t is outputting to a completely different directory to the one it is trying to load from).

It is also empty apart from:

    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252"?</br>  
    <SaveInformation xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'

Comment: the xml is empty because you don't have anything to save, right? you did not store any data to `public PlayerData[] stat` before serialization.

Comment: @kennyzx: if SHOULD be full. There is Data in it because i cannot save unless it is worked. However i will recheck to see it is being passed properly

Comment: **I have updated the original post to show the Classes the XML should be drawing the information from.** A debug showed that @kennyzx was right, the data was empty (i.e = null), however i was working fine in-game

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new instance of your class if you call save. Make sure you only have one instance that gets Loaded and Saved...

```
public class StoreData : MonoBehaviour {

    // this will hold your data (but in the snippets you provided I 
    // can't see how you are accessing this, maybe this should be public)
    private static SaveInformation saveInformation = null; // keep one instance

    private static string savepath = Application.dataPath; // or Application.persistentDataPath ?
    private static string savePathFile = Path.Combine(savepath, "SaveInformation.xml");

    public SaveInformation Instance {
       get {
           return (saveInformation ?? new SaveInformation());
       }
    }

    public static void Load(){
        saveInformation = SaveInformation.Load(savePathFile);
        Debug.Log("Loaded");
    }

    public static void Save(){
        if (saveInformation != null) {
           saveInformation.Save(savePathFile);
           Debug.Log("Saved");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("No saveinformation yet");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is much cleaner code than my original. However i am still getting "No Save Information Yet".
Would you mind having a look at the SaveInformation class and PlayerDatabase Class (1st and 3rd Method) to see if that is where i am going wrong?

Comment: tried to vote up but i do not have enough rep, could someone do it for me?

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve the problem. Your code was a much better way to write the StoreData Class and for that i am thankful but no datails being passed as saveInformation is null. If you could point out to me why I would like nothing better then to credit you with your answer.

Comment: Do you call StoreData.Load() anywhere?

Comment: I've added public statis Instance property on StoreData called Instance which you can use to store your playet info in ad then call Save on it....

Comment: Rene: Thanks again but it is still not passing information through. I am still getting. "No saveinformation yet". 
Is the List information not being passed properly? I am trying to call it through my GUI with StoreData.Save();